# Jenkins build failure:javac file not found

Tags: java, jenkins, compilation, javac

I am quite a newbie in Jenkins so I was trying to build a java project which is in git local repository but It fails to build, the error being that it can't find the source file:

D:\Apps\Jenkins\jobs\HelloWorld\workspace>javac HelloWorld.java 
     javac: file not found: HelloWorld.java

I used the following  batch command

```
                   javac HelloWorld.java
                   java HelloWorld
```

The absolute path to HelloWord.java is D:\JenJava\JenkinTest\src\com\testing

I used Eclipse to write the test program and my workspace is JenJava

My guess is that it points to the wrong directory hence javac can't find the source file.I would like to know if that is not the problem what then should be done,if it is how to correct it?.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you configured your JDK in Jenkins right?

Comment: @Baldurian     Yep Jdk is well configured infact When I try to execute a  simple HelloWorld.java which isn't in a package or folder it works!!

Answer (score 3):

You have to give the full path to the `.java` file to `javac`. For example:

Assuming the "current working directory" is `D:\JenJava`

```
javac JenkinTest\src\com\testing\HelloWorld.java
```

Or to use absolute path:

```
javac D:\JenJava\JenkinTest\src\com\testing\HelloWorld.java
```

However, it also sounds like you may need to learn some more about Jenkins. It should be able to compile Java projects without using a batch file with absolute paths. Have you investigated using Gradle, Ant, or Maven to script your build?